# I am trying to run the integration testing in Ruby on rails using capybara but when i run the test i am getting a java script error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, webrat

HTML code for Issue Slip

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @issue_slip do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  <b>From Store:</b></br>

<%= f.label :store_location_id %>
   <% if !current_user.store_location_id? %>
    <%= f.collection_select :store_location_id, StoreLocation.all,:id,:name, {:prompt => "Select Store"}, :style => 'width:205px;' %><br />
    <% else %>
    <%= f.collection_select :store_location_id, StoreLocation.all,:id,:name, :value => current_user.store_location_id %><br/>
    <% end %>

   <b>Delivery To:</b></br>

<% if @count == nil %> 
<div class = "shop_floors">
<%= f.label :shop_floor_id %>
<%= f.collection_select :shop_floor_id, ShopFloor.all,:id,:name, {:prompt => "-Select a Shopfloor"}, :style=>'width:150px;'%></div><br/>
<% else %>
<strong><%= f.label :shop_floor_id %>:<%= @issue_slip.shop_floor.name %></strong><br /><% end %>

<div class ="date">
 <%= f.label :date, "Date" %>
 <%= f.datepicker :date, :dateFormat => 'dd MM, yy',  :showOn => "both", :buttonImage => "/assets/calendar.gif", :buttonImageOnly => true, :changeMonth => true, :changeYear => true , :size =>20 %><br/></div>

<%= f.label :project_id %>
<%= f.text_field :project_id , :size => 20 %><br />

<%= f.label :employee_id, "Issued. By" %>
   <% if !current_user.employee_id? %>
    <%= f.collection_select :employee_id, Employee.all,:id,:name, {:prompt => "Select Employee"}, :style => 'width:205px;' %><br />
    <% else %>
    <%= f.collection_select :employee_id, Employee.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id), :id, :name %><br/>
    <% end %>

 <%= f.input :remarks, :label => 'Remarks', :input_html => { :size => 20} %><br/>

 <%= f.label :bom_quantity %>
 <%= f.text_field :bom_quantity, :size=> 20, :value => number_with_precision(f.object.bom_quantity , :precision => 3) %><br />

 <div class = "cust_order">
<%= f.label :customer_order_id %>
<%= f.collection_select :customer_order_id , CustomerPendingOrder.all, :id,:id, :prompt => "Select Customer Order" %></div> <br />

<div class = "bom">
<%= f.label :bill_of_material_id %>
<%= f.collection_select :bill_of_material_id, BillOfMaterial.all, :id, :title , :prompt => "Select a BOM", :style => 'width:205px;' %></div>
<div class="load_bom"><%= f.submit "Load BOM" %></div> <br/>  

 <hr>
    <%= f.fields_for :issue_slip_line_items do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'issue_slip_line_item_fields', :f => builder %>
     <%end%>

 <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add Product", :issue_slip_line_items %> </p>   

 <p><%= f.submit data: {:disable_with=>@submit_tag_label}%><div class="load_preview_issue_slip"><%= f.submit "preview", :style => 'width:130px;', data: {:disable_with=>"loading preview..."} %></div></p>
  <% end %> 

</p>
```

Issue Slip Line Item

```
<%= f.link_to_remove "Remove Product"%><br/>
<div class ="product">

    <%= f.association :product, :prompt =>"Select Product",  input_html: {data:{prices: prices}}, :collection => Product.in_stock %> </div>
        <%= image_tag :image , :class => "prodimage"%>
<div class = "productid">
    <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, :class=>"productid" %></div>
<br/>


<div class ="price"><%= f.label :price %><%= f.text_field :price, :size=>20, :value => number_with_precision(f.object.price, :precision => 2)%> </div><br/>

<div class = "qty">  
    <%= f.label :quantity, "Quantity"%>
    <%= f.text_field :quantity, :size=>20 , :value => number_with_precision(f.object.quantity, :precision => 3)%></div><br/>

    <%= f.label :amount %>
    <%= f.text_field :amount, :size=>20,:class =>"amt", :value => number_with_precision(f.object.amount, :precision => 2) %><br/>


    <!--%= f.label :customs_duty, "Custom Duty"%-->
    <!--%= f.text_field :customs_duty, :size=>20 %-->


</div>
 <hr/>
```

creating test case
issue_slips_spec.rb

```
  it "issue slips test", :js => true do
    click_link 'New Issue Slip'
    select('Inuit HAL', :from => 'Store location')
    expect{ page.should have_content 'New Issue Slip'}
    expect{ page.should have_content 'From Store'}
    expect{ page.should have_content 'Delivery To'}
    select('sample shopfloor', :from => 'Shop floor')
    expect{ page.should have_content 'Shop floor '}
    fill_in "Date", :with => "06 October, 2014"
    fill_in "Project", :with => "1993"
    select('Sample Employee', :from => 'Issued. By')
    fill_in "Remarks", :with => "There is no remarks to mention"
    fill_in "Bom quantity", :with => "2"
    expect{ page.should have_link 'Add Product'}
    click_link 'Add Product'
    select('Nike', :from => 'Product')
    fill_in "Price", :with => "1000"
    fill_in "Quantity", :with => "1"
    fill_in "Amount", :with => "1000"
    expect{ page.should have_link 'Back to List'}
    click_button 'Create Issue slip'


end
end
```

Error Message:

```
    Failures:

      1) Sign in issue slips test
          Failure/Error: select('Nike', :from => 'Product')
         Webrat::NotFoundError:
           Could not find field: "Product"

         # ./spec/requests/issue_slips_spec.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

    Finished in 47.31 seconds
    1 example, 1 failure

    Failed examples:

    rspec ./spec/requests/issue_slips_spec.rb:15 # Sign in issue slips test
```

In the above code the Add product link is the issue when i click the that link it should load up another form called as issue_slip_line_item there i have Product, Price, Amount, Quantity field in my case the test is not able to recognize the product field it is giving me the error unable to find the product, Actually when i click the add product link it should open the issue slip line item form, there i have field in which test case is failing to open the link please help

Comment: have you tried using the selenium driver and watching it in the browser?

Comment: could you format your code? It's hard to read without proper indentation

Comment: Nope i havn't, Selenium, for one reason or another, makes developers a little uneasy. It sometimes has issues in the development versions but, most importantly, it’s slow. It would be awesome if we could run JavaScript without actually waiting for the slow rendering of a GUI window.

There are some attempts to make this work, libraries such as HTML::Unit and Akephalos. They do a good job, but their JavaScript engines aren’t a perfect match for a real browser. If only there were a real browser that we could run without the GUI!

Comment: It would probably help to edit the question to have a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, the error message says that the test failing is "Sign in issue slips test", but the spec shared is for "issue receipt test"? We also have no idea what the page you are testing looks like (ie there is no HTML) - for all we know, the error is correct and there is no Product field.